# Make an Input field blank

Tags: php, html

I have a newsletter form i kinda want to manipulate. I have no access to the backend, where it's specified that the newsletter form requires a name and an email adress. But i only want an email adress.

Can I somehow make the input field of the name pass an blank value/or an empty value so that it will still pass through the php?

Comment: With JavaScript and CSS you could hide the element and remove the `required` attribute. To pass the PHP you must edit direkly the PHP file. Or you could set an default with JavaScript in your Field and every one have the same name.

Comment: That actually worked! Sorry for the easy question :) Thank you so much for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (if you are lucky enough) using Injections.

There's an easy way, but less chance of success. Go to the Inspect Element of your browser and edit the following attributes of the relevant input field.

```
value=''
```

And if it has a

```
required
```

attribute remove it. But if they have validated the form from the back-end (95% possibility), you would be wasting your time.

Read these,

- [Injection Attacks](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Injection-Attacks.html)